# Launching inline content using PrettyPhoto that can link to other inline content that loads into the same modal window?

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog, prettyphoto

Is it possible to launch inline content into a modal window using PrettyPhoto that has links to other inline content, and have it load into the same modal window without closing it? Almost like a few page microsite in a modal window....Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Here is the HTML. PrettyPhoto is up and running on the site just fine, so I did not include the javascript.

```
<a rel="prettyPhoto" href="#inline-1" title="Inline 1">INLINE-1</a>
<a rel="prettyPhoto" href="#inline-2" title="Inline 2">INLINE-2</a>

<!-- MODAL: INLINE-1 -->
<div id="#inline-1" style="display:none;">
    <p>Inline 1 Content</p>
    <p><a rel="prettyPhoto" href="#inline-2">Link from Inline 1 to Inline 2</a></p>
</div>
<!-- END MODAL: INLINE-1 -->

<!-- MODAL: INLINE-2 -->
<div id="inline-2" style="display:none;">
    <p>Inline 2 Content</p>
    <p><a  rel="prettyPhoto" href="#inline-1">Link from Inline 2 to Inline 1</a></p>
</div>
<!-- END MODAL: INLINE-2 -->
```